# Does Kendo UI for web supports List view with virtual scrolling

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, scroll, kendo-ui

I want to develop List view using kendo-UI, Angularjs, Web API, this list view should have auto scrolling(load data on demand).

My question is auto scrolling is possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not available out of the box, but it is 3rd most voted feature that users suggest to add on KendoUI Feedback, link for this suggestion: http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/127393-kendo-ui-feedback/suggestions/3306257-ui-web-listview-endless-scrolling

> Based on our experience with virtualization cases like the grid and
>   the mobile list view, we consider a reusable implementation that
>   satisfies the above as a very complex one, which has a fairly limited
>   scope of use cases.

So, most likely they implement some other feature that could be used like listView with virtualScrolling and much more.

Anyway if you have fixed sizes of elements and you just want to load more elements when you scroll down it's not hard to implement it. You just have to detect scroll down event in your container, load more elements and add it to listView dataSource.

Comment: OK Thanks alot Jarsolaw!